# How to add user meta for all users

Tags: users

I am tring to build a point system for users. To save points I thought to use user meta. So I need to create a meta user called poins for all cureent users as well as futures users.

add_user_meta function need a user id. So will I have to use a loop?

Answer (score 5):

yes, you would have to loop through `all` users so that you could then update that user_meta field:

```
// Create the WP_User_Query object
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query(array('role' => 'Subscriber'));

// Get the results
$users = $wp_user_query->get_results();

// Check for results
if (!empty($users)) {

    // loop trough each author
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        // add points meta all the user's data
        add_user_meta( $user->id, 'points', '5', true ); // 5 = number of points existing users will get
    }
}
```

as far as adding this same user_meta to new users you could hook into the login or registration, depending on how you are adding them to the system.  for this you could use `get_current_user_id()` to get the id of that unique user.

later, you could then just `update_user_meta($user_id,'points');` in whatever function they are earning more points at.

you can find more info on the [WP_User_Query in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

Comment: After adding this code to functions.php and after a page refresh can I remove the code again?

Comment: Yes, you could remove the code once the users received this meta.

Comment: if you like this answer, could you please mark it as 'answered' ?

Comment: What about new users?

Comment: @marek.m `as far as adding this same user_meta to new users you could hook into the login or registration, depending on how you are adding them to the system. for this you could use get_current_user_id() to get the id of that unique user.`  <- within original answer... you just need to get the id of the user ( through login or registration )... this is obviously dependent on how/where you are capturing the new user info in the first place.